# React Router 4 Nested Routes not rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I'm trying to do nested routing in one of my components.

Here's the parent component:

```
const App = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Landing} />
        <Route path="/contribute" component={Contribute} />
      </Switch>
    </Provider>
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

And here's the child component:

```
const Landing = () => (
  <div>
    <SearchBar />
    <section className="results-sctn">
      <Route exact path="/" component={ArtistList} />
      <Route path="/test" component={Test} />
    </section>
  </div>
);
```

`ArtistList` renders fine on the `/` route, but `/test` renders a totally blank page. Any idea why this might be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This behaviour happens because have an `exact` attribute mentioned on the parent route

```
<Route exact path="/" component={Landing} />
```

So what happens is that react-router sees a path `/test` to match and then tries to match it starting from the top level. and it sees two routes one is `exactly /` and other is `/contribute`. None of them match the required path and hence you see a blank page

You need to write

```
<Route path="/" component={Landing} />
```

So when you do this, it will see `/` which matches `/test` partially and then will try to find a matched route in the `landing` component which it will find.

Also change the order of the parent Route, since `Switch` renders the first match and `/` is a partial match for `/test` so `/contribute` wont work

Your final code would look like

```
const App = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/contribute" component={Contribute} />
        <Route path="/" component={Landing} />
      </Switch>
    </Provider>
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

Comment: Aha! Thank you for the clear answer, extremely helpful.

Comment: Thank you, I was trying setup this after migrate to router 4 for days!