# Trying to go back to "/" in react router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

So what I want is to have a top-level routing in `App.js` that routes to 
`Home` on "/". In `Home` i want to render a few things and then one place where I chose what to render based on the path.

i.e. if the path is "/" I want to show a `Link` that can take me to "/about", if the path is "/about" I'll show the `About` component there.

In `App.js` I always have a `Link` that can take me back to "/".

---

So `App.js` render this:

```
  <Router>
    <div>          
      <Link to="/">
        <button>Go to home</button>
      </Link>
      <Route exact path="/" component={() => <Home/>} />
      <Route exact path="/other" component={() => <Other/>} />
    </div>
  </Router>
```

`Home` render this:

```
  <div>
    THIS IS HOME WOO!
    <Router>
      <div>
        <Route exact path="/" component={() => <HomeController/>} />
        <Route exact path="/about" component={() => <About/>} />
      </div>
    </Router>
  </div>
```

`HomeController` render this:

```
  <Link to="/about">
    <button>Go to about</button>
  </Link>
```

and `About` render this:

```
  <div>
    ABOUT
  </div>
```

---

When I start the app it looks like this:

[image]

When I click 'Go to about' it looks like this:

[image]

correctly updating the url and what is showed by the router in `Home`

But if I now click on 'Go to home' this happens:

[image]

correctly updating the url but keeping the 'about' page when rendering `Home`?

---

Why is this? Why does "/" seem to still route to "/about"? What would I need to change to make the button route back to "/" and show the 'Go to about'-button again?

Here is all the code I used to recreate the issue: [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/qLuHGA02)

Comment: Why are you using two different `<Router>` components here? If you just remove the `<Router>` inside your `Home` component it should work how you want it to. You don't need a new `<Router>` as parent every time you want to define routes. The Router can be a distant parent and it will still work.

Comment: Oh! Thank you, I should obviously spend more time learning how react-router-dom works. On mobile now but will try it out in a few minutes

Comment: Alright, I removed the `<Router>` component in `Home` but then it doesn't look like it's rendering `About` inside of `Home`. More specifically, when clicking 'Go to about' the "THIS IS HOME WOO!" disappear and is completely replaced by "ABOUT".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things that you need to correct.

**First**, you must have just a single Router in your App and not nested Router

**Second**, If you have an exact keyword on the parent Route then the nested Routes won't match since the match will fails at the parent itself

**Third**, Then you don't want to pass custom props to the child component, you must render them like `component={Home}` and not `component={() => <Home/>}` and if you want to pass props to children, you must use `render` and not `component` prop and write `render={(props) => <Home test="1" {...props}}`

Your complete code will look like

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Router>
          <div>
            <Link to="/">
              <button>Go to home</button>
            </Link>
            <Route path="/" component={Home} />
            <Route exact path="/other" component={Other} />
          </div>
        </Router>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="home">
        <div>
          <Route exact path="/" component={HomeController} />
          <Route exact path="/about" component={About} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class HomeController extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="homecontroller">
        <Link to="/about">
          <button>Go to about</button>
        </Link>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class About extends Component {
  render() {
    return <div className="about">ABOUT</div>;
  }
}

class Other extends Component {
  render() {
    return <div className="other">OTHER</div>;
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

**[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/jp22zvo7l3)**

You can refer the following question for more details

[Passing custom props to router component in react-router v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44255415/passing-custom-props-to-router-component-in-react-router-v4/44255850#44255850)

[React Router 4 Nested Routes not rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47308065/react-router-4-nested-routes-not-rendering)

Comment: Thanks for a great answer! The first two points fixed the problem. A question on the last part though: why is that? For example in my real code I now have this route: `<Route exact path={routes.SELECT} component={() => <Select model={model} explorable={this.state.explorable}/>} />` and it works, in `Select` I can access `model` and `explorable` through `this.props`. So I'm assuming there's a reason I don't want to do it this way? What does the `{...props}` part imply?

Comment: @MrJalapeno, It sure works, however its a good practice to use render, please refer to the first link that I added in my answer, it will explain you as to why you need `{...props}`

Answer (score 1):

Delete the `<Router />` entries from `Home`

Make the following adjustments to `App.js`  I noticed `/other` was listed instead of `About` component for `/about` Route.  If it's correct leave it alone otherwise adjust it to `About` component as below.  You do need to import these components at the top so i'm assuming you are already doing this.

```
  <Router>
    <div>          
      <Link to="/">
        <button>Go to home</button>
      </Link>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route exact path="/about" component={About} />
    </div>
  </Router>
```

for `Home.js`, you need to render `<HomeController />`

```
  <div>
    THIS IS HOME WOO!
    <HomeController />
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks but it didn't fix my pickle :(

On "/about" I want to render `About` _inside_ of `Home`, that is, I want to see both the content of `Home` ("THIS IS HOME WOO") and the content of `About` ("ABOUT") where it replaces the HomeController (the "Go to about"-button)

I'm wondering if I'm taking some fundamental wrong path for solving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to make the following changes:

`App.js`:
Change Router to Switch, change the order of the Routes and set "/" to a relative path

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/other" component={() => <Other/>} />
  <Route path="/" component={() => <Home/>} />
</Switch>
```

Remove the Router from `Home`:

```
<div>
  THIS IS HOME WOO!
  <div>
      <Route exact path="/" component={() => <HomeController/>} />
      <Route exact path="/about" component={() => <About/>} />
  </div>
</div>
```