# do something, then reroute in react

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Short version: When the user clicks a button, I want to do something, then reroute the user. How do I do this?

---

Longer version:

I have nested routes (don't know if this has any effect to the problem at hand) how this is setup is described in a pretty minimal (to the best of my knowledge) example here: [link to SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49921290/trying-to-go-back-to-in-react-router)

I want a button, that first does something, then reroutes the user, therefore I can't use `Link`. First all I saw was

> use `this.props.history.push('/route')` for that

But then I learned that `this.props.history` isn't a thing anymore and is now it's own npm package. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42672842/how-to-get-history-on-react-router-v4)  I got a simple explenation on how to implement what I needed.

---

Example of my problem:

`App.js` render this:

```
<Router history={history}>
  <div>          
    <Link to="/">
      <button>Go to home</button>
    </Link>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/other" component={() => <Other/>} />
    <Route path="/" component={() => <Home/>} />
  </Switch>
  </div>
</Router>
```

With two top level routes, an exact path for `/other` that render `Other` and looks like this:

[image]

and a relative path for `/` that render `Home` and looks like this:

[image]

`Home` renders this code:

```
<div>
  THIS IS HOME WOO!
  <div>
      <Route exact path="/" component={() => <HomeController/>} />
      <Route exact path="/about" component={() => <About/>} />
      <Route exact path="/click-page" component={() => <ClickPage/>} />              
  </div>
</div>
```

Now here the default is `HomeController` (containing two buttons with links to about and click-page), but `/about` renders `About` and looks like this:

[image]

and `/click-page` renders `ClickPage` and looks like this:

[image]

---

This is where the problem starts :(

So `ClickPage` renders this:

```
<button onClick={clickHandler}>
  DO SOMETHING THEN GO TO ABOUT
</button>
```

where `clickHandler` looks like this:

```
function clickHandler(){
  console.log("doing stuff");
  history.push('/about');
}
```

`history` in this case is imported from another file that looks like this:

```
// history.js
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history'

export default createBrowserHistory({
/* pass a configuration object here if needed */
})
```

which is character by character copied from the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42672842/how-to-get-history-on-react-router-v4) i mentioned earlier.

Problem is, when I click the button, this is what I see:

[image]

So the function is called, it does something, and then it pushes "/about" to history, but nothing happens. Why is this? Do I need to force `Home` to rerender?

The full example code I've used to recreate the issue is here: [pastebin-link](https://pastebin.com/4MtrZEME)

Comment: Can you make a Codesandbox example and I'll take a look?

Comment: Sure! Thanks a lot! Here's a link to a copy: https://codesandbox.io/s/61pm121vkw

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to push to History in React Router v4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42701129/how-to-push-to-history-in-react-router-v4)

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42701129/how-to-push-to-history-in-react-router-v4/45849608#45849608

Comment: @MrJalapeno is this behavior what you want? https://codesandbox.io/s/w21m5mlvyw

Comment: Yes, that is exactly the behavior I wanted. Thank you. I feel stupid for not just trying "this.props.history.push" directly, but I guess I just assumed it wouldn't work after reading the other post.

Comment: Cool, I'll add it as an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

First thing is that,

```
this.props.history.push('/route')
```

is still present in the react-router4. the history prop is only available to the direct child of Router.

In case ur component is not direct child of the Router, u can export that component using the **withRouter** HOC, which can be imported like this

```
import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom'
```

then, on click of button, u can do ur stuff, and use

```
this.props.history.push('/route')
```

to go to any location

Answer (score 0):

You can use `this.history.push` in any component rendered by a `Route`.

Example code here: https://codesandbox.io/s/w21m5mlvyw

Comment: Cool! Working on implementing it, I think I might have also learned a reason to use `component={ClickPage}` instead of `component={() => <ClickPage/>`. If I just remove `history={history} from `Router` and change it to `this.props.history.push` I get an error that `props` doesn't have `history`. But if I change it to be exactly your code it works. Gonna look closer as to what more is needed.

Comment: Yeah, I recommend using the `component={Component}` pattern. If it helps, feel free to mark as correct :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this ..

```
import { Redirect } from 'react-router'
...

render() {
...

{fireRedirect && (
  <Redirect to={from || '/thank-you'}/>
)}
```

Update your **fireRediect** state after your user action is completed

[This](https://gist.github.com/verticalgrain/195468e69f2ac88f3d9573d285b09764) looks like something you need here.