# React router not rendering path component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I my app.js I have defined a route as:

```
<PrivateRoute exact={true} path="/servicePanel" component={ServicePanel} />
```

and in my `ServicePanel.js` I have a link as:

```
<Link to={`${this.props.match.url}/fileManagerDashboard`}>
    <i className="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></i>
    File Manager
</Link>
<Switch>
    <PrivateRoute path={`${this.props.match.path}/fileManagerDashboard`} component={Dashboard} />
</Switch>
```

but the issue is that this `/servicePanel/fileManagerDashboard` path is not found when I set the prop `exact={true} in aboue path

```
<PrivateRoute exact={true} path="/servicePanel" component={ServicePanel} />
```

and when I don't set exact={true} in the above path, `/servicePanel/fileManagerDashboard` renders both `/servicePanel` path component and below it `/fileManagerDashboard` path component on the same page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that You don't want to render the ServicePanel component on `/servicePanel/fileManagerDashboard`, you need to refactor the Routes to add `/servicePanel/fileManagerDashboard` at the same level as `/servicePanel`

Your Routes would look like

```
<Switch>
      <PrivateRoute exact={true} path="/servicePanel" component={ServicePanel} />
      <PrivateRoute path={`${this.props.match.path}/fileManagerDashboard`} component={Dashboard} />
</Switch>
```

and ServicePanel component will contain just the link

```
<Link to={`${this.props.match.url}/fileManagerDashboard`}>
    <i className="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></i>
    File Manager
</Link>
```

Comment: as you said I need to add `/servicePanel/fileManagerDashboard` and this `/servicePanel` at the same level, can I do that in app.js???

Comment: @User101 you can do that where you have written your Routes or depending on where exactly you want to render your Components.

Comment: I have wriiten this `<PrivateRoute exact={true} path="/servicePanel" component={ServicePanel} />` in my app.js and I have written this `    <PrivateRoute path={`${this.props.match.path}/fileManagerDashboard`} component={Dashboard} />` in my ServicePanel.js.

is there any way I can manage this in my `ServicePanel.js`

Comment: In that case you must have `<PrivateRoute path={\`${this.props.match.path}/fileManagerDashboard\`} component={Dashboard} />` in app.js, if you add it in ServicePanel, until ServicePanel is rendered, Dashboard cannot, so they won't be mutually exclusive of each other

Comment: i added both my routes `<PrivateRoute path={'/servicePanel/fileManagerDashboard'} component={Dashboard} />` and 
                    `<PrivateRoute path="/servicePanel" component={ServicePanel} />` in app.js and removed all routes from servicePanel.js just left the `<Link>...</Link>` there and now it is working.....is this fine or is there any better way to achieve this.

Comment: The above mentioned way should be used when ServicePanel and Dashboard component need to be mutually exclusive of each other and is the right way. However in a case where you would want both of them to render, you could just remove the exact keyword from ServicePanel Route from your original question and it would work.

Comment: You could check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43994510/react-router-v4-renders-multiple-routes/43994605#43994605 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49921290/trying-to-go-back-to-in-react-router/49927990#49927990 for more details

Comment: I wanted them to be mutually exclusive....if the route is `/servicePanel` just load the `ServicePanel.js` component and if the route is `/servicePanel/fileManagerDashboard` just load the `Dashboard.js` component only

Comment: As I said, for your mentioned case, the above solution is how your handle it.